# How to disable Kafka hostname verification for client scripts?

Tags: apache-kafka, verification, hostname

Do you know how can I disable Kafka hostname verification for using Kafka scripts such as `kafka-console-consumer.sh`?

This is my config right now:

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
sasl.mechanism=JWT
```

I have set the `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm` to an empty string as you see above, but still I get this error:

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:445)
```

I call the script as follows:

```
$KAFKAHOME/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh \
--consumer.config myconfig.config \
--bootstrap-server  myaddress:myport\
--topic mytopic
```

Comment: Can you add the full command you use to invoke `kafka-console-consumer.sh`? Thanks

Comment: @MickaelMaison I added.

Comment: I had the same error and reason was incorrect key and trust store files supplied in config

Answer (score 2):

I believe your client config is missing a path to the truststore file.

For example, this is my `client.properties` file

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/security/server/server-truststore.jks
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
```

Comment: this is the key configuration:  ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=